# What is "first-order minimax-optimal"?

Tags: statistics, decision-theory

I saw the phrase "first-order minimax-optimal" in a paper and was wondering what it means.
From wiki I know what "minimax-optimal" means, but "first-order minimax-optimal"?

Comment: Can you give us a link of that paper?

Comment: "First order" typically means you're only checking gradient (or subgradient) values -- no Hessians to characterize whether you're at a minimum or a max, etc. This includes critical points.

Comment: link: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/10.1080/01621459.2018.1429274. Search for "first-order"